# Como puedo modificar una foto en mysql con PHP el codigo que coloco no me la modifica ni me arroja error

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el código php que utilizo para modificar la imagen pero no me quiere guardar la ruta nueva y tampoco me arroja un error de sintaxis o de conexión, simplemente no me realiza el update
Quien me pueda ayudar a resolverlo seria un gran apoyo.

```
if( isset($_FILES['fot_usu']) ) {
        $fot_usu = $_FILES['fot_usu'];

     }
     if( isset($_POST['niv_acc']) ) {
        $niv_acc = $_POST['niv_acc'];

     }
     if( isset($_POST['est_usu']) ) {
        $est_usu = $_POST['est_usu'];

     }
     if( isset($_POST['boton']) ) {
        $boton = $_POST['boton'];

     }

    echo isset($boton);
    if (isset($boton)=="Modificar Registro")
      {
            $sql="SELECT * from usuario where cod_usu='$cod_usu'";
              $respuesta= mysqli_query ($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
               if ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta))
                  {     
            $nombrefoto = $_FILES["fot_usu"]["name"];
            $foto    = rand(0,9).rand(100,9999).rand(100,9999).".".$nombrefoto;
            $ruta = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"]; //localizacion actual del archivo
            $destino = "../../Imagenes/Fotos/".$foto; //lugar en el que se quiere copiar
            $selecionar = "SELECT fot_usu FROM usuario WHERE cod_usu = '$cod_usu'";
            $resultado_seleccionar = mysqli_query($link, $selecionar);

            $foto_db = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_seleccionar);
            $ruta_foto_db = "../Imagenes/Fotos/" . $foto_db['foto'];

            if(file_exists($ruta_foto_db)){
            unlink($ruta_foto_db);
            }

            if (!file_exists($destino)) {
            move_uploaded_file($ruta,$destino);
            }






                       $sql="update usuario set nom_usu='$nom_usu', apel_usu='$apel_usu', area_usu='$area_usu', login='$login',  password='$password', niv_acc='$niv_acc', est_usu='$est_usu' where cod_usu='$cod_usu'";
                       $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                    if ($result)
                        {       
                            ?>
                                <script>
                                    alert ("Registro Actualizado");
                                    window.location="Index.php";
                                </script>                   
                            <?php
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

En todas las consultas, trata cambiarlo de esta manera:
 **- Cambiar esta:**

```
$sql="SELECT * from usuario where cod_usu='$cod_usu'";
```

**- Por esta:**

```
$sql="SELECT * from usuario where cod_usu='".$cod_usu."'"; //Se agregaron comillas y puntos
```

---

### Te pongo los Querys faltantes corregidos.

```
$selecionar = "SELECT fot_usu FROM usuario WHERE cod_usu = '".$cod_usu."'";
$sql="update usuario set nom_usu='".$nom_usu."', apel_usu='".$apel_usu."',area_usu='".$area_usu."', login='".$login."',  password='".$password."', niv_acc='".$niv_acc."', est_usu='".$est_usu."' where cod_usu='".$cod_usu."'";
```

Comment: gracias por la idea, la probe ero igualmente no me almacena el campo de la foto.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error aquí

```
if (isset($boton)=="Modificar Registro"){
  // stuff
}
```

Ya que [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) Te regresa un booleano, y tu estás intentando compararlo con una cadena, por lo cual jamás entrará en ese `if`

Podrías corregirlo así

```
if ( isset( $boton ) ) {
  if ( $boton == "Modificar Registro" ){
    // stuff
  }    
}
```

De esa manera quizá si entre, eso depende que traiga tu variable `$boton`

**Edito**
Debido al comentario te comento, deberás entonces hacer una validación anidada. Primero preguntar si botón tiene un valor, y luego validar si botón es igual a la cadena. Reitero si lo dejas estarás comparando algo así `if( boolean == string )` y eso hace que tus consultas jamás entren.

Comment: debo colocar el isset() puesto que si no lo hago me arroja un notice de que la variable no ha sido definida y no ejecuta la accion.

Comment: Ya edité mi respuesta, revisalo.

Comment: ya lo edite pero igualmente no me hace el update de la fotografia.